# How can I interface the msp430G2553 with a GSM Module using energia

Tags: gsm, at-command, serial-communication, msp430

I am using an MSP430g2553 rev 1.5 to interface with a Sim800L GSM module. I have tried running my code on energia to send an sms but I have not been able to have the gsm work. The GSM is connected to the network (according to the led status) but I do not know what is causing the issue.

I have tried using the code from user VigneshRaja on another post to test my board. I have provided it below. I do have a few concerns:

1. The code shown below if for hardware serial communication correct? So I would have to orient the UART jumpers to match hardware communication and i would have to connect my P1_1 to txd and P1_2 to Rxd of another board. Everything else would be fine.
2. The phone number listed below is a dummy number but I am confused as to what I should use for my number? Do I include the plus sign of my number, followed by my international code (1 for USA) and then my personal number?

Any help would be appreciated. This is the updated code:

```
char response;
char message;
void setup()
{
    Serial.begin(9600);
    Serial1.begin(9600);

    Serial.println("Initializing...");
    delay(1000);

    Serial1.println("AT"); 
    updateSerial();
    Serial1.println("AT+CMGF = 1\r");
    delay(1000);
    updateSerial();
    Serial1.println("AT+CMGS =\"1234567891\"\r");
    delay(2000);
    updateSerial();
    Serial1.println("HELLO WORLD");
    delay(1000);
    updateSerial();
    Serial1.println((char)26);
    delay(100);
    updateSerial();
}

void loop()
{
    updateSerial();
}

void updateSerial()
{
    delay(500);
    while (Serial.available()) 
    {
        Serial1.println(Serial.read());//Forward what Serial received to Software 
        Serial Port
    }
    while(Serial1.available()) 
    {
        response = Serial1.read();
        Serial.write(response);//Forward what Software Serial received to Serial Port
    }
}
```

In the serial monitor i get the following response:

```
Initializing...
AT

OK
AT+CMGF = 1


AT+CMGS ="12345HELLO WORLD
```

Why does it only send some of my number and then send HELLO WORLD without any spaces between the previous command?

Comment: Even assuming that all the serial pin connections are fine, you are for sure sending your sms to early: the phone might be unregistered to the network, yet. I suggest to start making sure that the communication with modem is active, by reading modem responses. Start waiting for 'Ok' after 'AT'.

Comment: @Cubo78 I understant. I will try this and get back to you if i find anything.

Comment: @Cubo78 Okay when I program my msp430 using energia and a simple code I will get what I want almost 1/8th of the time. Most of the time I get an error and the code does not upload. The code is shown as follows:

    void setup(){
    Serial.begin(9600);
    }
 
    void loop(){
    Serial.print("Hello");
    delay(1000);
    }

So before i can even test my module I need to get this working properly. I will try switching out the msp430g2553 since I doubt any other hardware issue is the problem (I have my hardware set to hardware serial already).

Comment: @Cubo78 Turns out the MSP430g2553 is defunct when using serial with energia due to the lack of EZFet but I changed to the MSP432FR5969 and I cant get the serial monitor working. Now when I send an "AT" command to the gsm I get the same numbers: "84 13 10 65" any idea what that means? Does that mean my baud rate is wrong or what?

Comment: You receive ONLY those bytes? And in that order? 84=0x54 = 'T', 13=0x0D='\r', 10=0x0A='\n', 65=0x41='A'. So, if the actual order is 65 84 13 10, what you are seing is `AT\r\n`, the echo of your command.

Comment: @Cubo78 ah that isnt good. Perhaps my coding is not correct or my wiring is not properly set up. I will keep working on the project to see what I can do. I tried converting the message that was sent directly to ASCII but I did not realize it had to be converted to hex first.

Comment: @Cubo78 Alright after trying different things I cannot get it to work. I checked to see if a signal was coming from the TX pin of the gsm to make sure that the message I receive is from the gsm, the oscilloscope shows that the gsm is sending the message. Is this code correct for trying to connect the gsm? I still only get what I put in but that makes sense since the gsm echoes what you put in but it should respond with its answer too.

Comment: Alright i cant figure out how to type code in the comments :(

Comment: Don't write code in comments. Just edit the question. How do.you read data from modem? I don't see in yourcode any serial.read o something similar..

Comment: @Cubo78 I have updated the question with the code.

Comment: Well it turns out that I needed to connect the ground of the gsm to the ground of the msp430. Now when I send "AT" I get back OK but then the module does not return the code that follows. For example, I will send "AT\r" and it will return "OK" then I send "AT+CMGF = 1\r" and the module responds with "AT+CM" and it stops responding to anything else.

Comment: Well done (for the HW fix). What I don't understand is: in sendSMS() how do you read data from modem? I only see send commands.

Comment: @Cubo78 I have updated the code with the code that also reads the data. I also placed what the response of the serial monitor is.

Comment: In case anyone else ever has this issue I will explain how I solved my error. Firstly, make sure you ground your gsm battery at the same place you ground your gsm itself. Secondly, if you are using msp make sure to increase the buffer size of your RX pin in energia. Go to your energia installation >hardware> energia>msp430>cores>msp430 and find the HardwareSerial.cpp file. Go into it and change #define SERIAL_BUFFER_SIZE 16 to #define SERIAL_BUFFER_SIZE 32. After this i was able to get a complete response from the gsm and I was able to debug my AT commands. Thank you for the help @Cubo78.